# Why not just use causal perturbation theory instead?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, perturbation-theory

Why would one bother with counter-term renormalization (and any other old-fashioned strategies that cancel infinities in calculation) when there is causal perturbation theory, which is mathematically rigorous?

Comment: Might be worth noting that weak-coupling perturbation theory doesn't converge in most QFTs of interest. This is true even if we start with lattice QFT, which is *nonperturbatively* well-defined. Causal perturbation theory might make individual terms in the weak-coupling series well-defined, but it still doesn't doesn't make the series converge.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Wouldn't this be a problematic case for both old-fashioned and causal perturbation methods?

Comment: Whether it's problematic or not depends on what you're doing. These series are typically asymptotic. This is usually the case in classical perturbation theory as well.

Comment: @jrex Yes. Like Richard Myers said, the series are typically asymptotic. An asymptotic series can appear to be converging up to the first $N$ terms, for some finite $N$, but then it turns a corner and becomes increasingly divergent as more terms are included. A classic example is $\int^\infty_{-\infty} dx\ \exp(-m^2x^2-gx^4)$. The integral is well-defined if $g\geq 0$, but the expansion in powers of $g$ does not converge. You can anticipate this by observing that the integral is ill-defined for $g<0$, so the radius of convergence of the $g$-expansion must be zero.

Comment: Thanks. Would there be any advantage to using old-fashioned renormalization over causal perturbation theory? Is it simply easier to use? (Not just in this case, but in general.)